# Upgraded to 14.04, now okular dies

Tags: kubuntu, okular

I upgraded my KUbuntu system to 14.04, and now when I start it, it opens up a window, then puts the following messages:

```
$ okular ar.drone2_User-guide_UK.pdf 
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0".
Can't get XRandR version 
okular: Fatal IO error: client killed
```

and then the window closes. I can't find anything in any log file.

Comment: Maybe connected - a KDE bug report: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=333639 . Are you using xinerama ? Is the xRandR disabled ?

Comment: @user26687 The answer to those questions would be yes and yes.

Comment: My bug report is at https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=334088. I also found https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=331784 which also affects me (kded dies the same way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported the bug [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=334088) and supposedly the patches have been submitted but not taken yet. Meanwhile, if you set the environment variable `KSCREEN_BACKEND=Fake`, okular and kded both start working again.